# How do I send out alerts when a document is approved

Tags: 2007, workflow, content-approval

Is there anyway to send out an alert when a document passes content approval. Ie a group of users should get emailed when any documents in a particular document library go from pending to approved status?

I see options to send out an alert when a document is add, modified, deleted, but not approved.

I tried to set this up as an approval workflow, but that didn't quite work out right. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're on the right track.

You can create a document approval workflow or edit the out of the box workflows via sharepoint designer (Make sure to copy the document approval workflow and start with the new copy). Add a step to the completion box to send an email if the status is approved.

Check this [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/use-an-approval-workflow-HA010154425.aspx) for more info on editing out of the box workflows.

Make sure, to save, publish, and associate the workflow after creation.

Let me know if that helps.